# Understanding the Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If a sample is normal with observations independent and identically distributed:

$\mu|\sigma^2 \propto N(\beta \,,\,\sigma^2/\, n_0)$

How can I show that 
$\mu\,|\,x_1,x_2,....x_n\,,\,\sigma^2 \sim N(\frac {n\bar{x} + n_o\beta}{ n + n_o} \, , \frac {\sigma^2}{n + n_o})$ ? I have been trying to figure this out for days.  Originally I assumed both the mean and $x_1,....x_n$ were normally distributed and the the variance as chi squared distributed but I have don't know how to incorporate all three in a manner to get a normal distribution.